# How do i handle ajax and closing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

If the user happens to have a delay in connecting to my site, the ajax hasnt timed out and the user decides to close the window. The ajax query will be terminated? Is there a way i can say still processing are you close you want to leave this page? (bonus if it will close once ajax was successful). How do i do this?

I am not sure if this is the same thing (maybe its built into firefox?) but when i closed this page it said

> Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?
>
> You have started writing or editing a post.
>
> Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.

I am positive i seen this other places. How do i make this appear when the user isnt submitting ajax and is in the middle of a post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)** event to handle this. Set a variable to false at the start of the ajax request. And in the callback function set its value to true, and in the `window.onbeforeunload` event check that variable and display suitable message.

***Note***

This will fire when you refresh your page also.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the onbeforeunload handler in js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
   if (showMessage)
   {
      return trye
   }
   else
   {
      return;
   }
}
```